# how to overcome blockOptional is blocking in spring web flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I'm currently working on a streaming exercise, and here's the situation: I'm receiving a stream of tokens when I hit an endpoint, and my job is to save each of these tokens as they arrive. After the entire stream is processed, I need to use the Discord client to send the collected tokens to a Discord channel. I've included the code signature below. The problem I'm encountering is that `blockOptional() is causing blocking, and it's not supported in the reactor-http-nio-15 thread`. Any advice on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
var dataStream = chatBotRPCService.getResponseUsingStreaming(message.getContent());


// data stream is of type Flux<Object>


processStreamDataFlux(dataStream, message, chatBot, dmMessage, externalFunctionCallCount, answer, response)
    .doOnComplete(() -> {
          
           //send the accumulated tokens to discord  
           
           // The issue happens at the below line of code. 

           messageData = discordClient
                    .getChannelById(Snowflake.of(message.getThreadId()))
                    .createMessage(
                            MultipartRequest.ofRequest(messageRequest
                            )).blockOptional();
       
    })
    .subscribe(tokens -> {
    });
```

`Issue: blockOptional() is blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-15`

discord client is built on the package `https://github.com/Discord4J/Discord4J`

Comment: Does `processStreamDataFlux` return Flux and `discordClient. ... .createMessage` - Mono?

Comment: processStreamDataFlux returns flux and discordClient. ... .createMessage.  doesn't return anything. It just sends a message on doOnCompleteCall @gdomo

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `doOnComplete` which is using a Runnable as parameter, you can use `collectList` which will return a Mono<List<?>>. After that, you can use `flatMap` on this Mono and call the `createMessage` as the return statement of the flat map.